# Comparing component class to undefined gives true

Tags: javascript, angular, angular8

I have a component where I am trying to inject the component dynamically.

```
export class ModalPopupComponent implements ModalInjectable {

  open : boolean = true

  injectedComponent : ModalInjection

  @Input('injection')   injection   : ModalInjection
  @Input('injector')    injector    : ModalInjector
  @Input('title')       title       : string

  @ViewChild(
    'modalBody', 
    { static : true }) modalBody : ElementRef

  @ViewChild(
    'dynamicComponent', 
    { read : ViewContainerRef, static : true }) dynamicComponent : ViewContainerRef

  constructor(private componentFactoryResolver  : ComponentFactoryResolver,
              private changeDetectorRef         : ChangeDetectorRef) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.injection !== null, this.injection !== undefined)
    if (this.injection !== null) {
      this.open = true

      this.setupModalBody()
    } else {
      this.open = false
    }
  }

  setupModalBody() {
    const comp              = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(this.injection as any)
    this.injectedComponent  = this.dynamicComponent.createComponent(comp).instance as ModalInjection
    this.injectedComponent.setInjectionInfo(this.injector, this)
    this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges()
  }

  close() {
    this.open     = false
    this.injector = null
    this.injectedComponent.closeCB()
    this.injectedComponent = null
    this.dynamicComponent.remove(0)
  }

}
```

Here `injection` will be the component that is to be injected and `injector` is the component who is requesting to inject the component and `ModalInjector` and `ModalInjection` is an interface.

The problem which got now is that `this.injection !== null, this.injection !== undefined` this expression is resulting `true, false` instead of `true, true` I had put the log whether I am getting the value for `injection` and `injector` or not but I am getting the value too.

Image for error is [image: here]. I am not able to figure out what is the mistake.

EDIT

I am invoking this modal popup as

```
this.av.getLayout().showModalPopup(AddScComponent as any, this, 'Create Sale Category')
```

Comment: speaking from a purely javascript point of view, `injection` never seems to be initialised with any value, so, yes, it would be undefined  - but that doesn't take into consideration the jiggery pokery angular/typescript does, so my comment may be irrelevant

Comment: you may be right because I am passing the class name directly. Check my edit

Answer (score 0):

You have not bootstrapped the component as an [entry component](https://angular.io/guide/entry-components).

Add the following to your `@NgModule({ ... })` declaration:

```js
@NgModule({
  // ...declarations, imports, providers, etc.
  bootstrap: [ModalPopupComponent],
})
```

Comment: ModalPopupComponent is not getting dynamically added. Component is getting added inside ModalPopupComponent dynamically